# Using a template page parent breaks page

Tags: categories, templates, wp-admin

So I have a Resources page that list several different resource post by category. Then under Resources I want to have a Whitepapers page that list all the post with a category of 'whitepaper'.

When I make the Whitepapers page have the parent Resources the page quits using the custom template and reverts to using the index.php layout. When I remove the parent the custom template works fine.

I'm using a permalink plugin so I can make the url structure they way I want. Just the admin gets messier with both Resources and Whitepapers at the same level instead of -Whitepapers within Resources. Also, once this is fixed I'll have several more categories under Resources.

Just trying to understand the underlying problem because I have News and Events category pages using the About-Us parent with no problems. Thanks for helping a Wordpress newbie...

Comment: Without knowing exactly what that plugin is doing, it's hard to say what the problem may be.

Comment: This is the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ But I don't think that this is the problem. I feel's like a weird hierarchy issue. I also have several templates being used with lot's of other parent/child relationships to different pages.

Comment: Inspect the contents of the `$wp_query` global on that page- this will show you how the query vars are set and the actual SQL being sent to the database. I don't see how the cause could be anything but that plugin.